# Need help scaling an image inside a viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, scale

I have a Django site that displays an image and I need to zoom in and zoom out using a button while keeping the viewport relatively the same size and use scroll bars to move the image when it is zoomed in. I am not a CSS nor javascript guy, so this attempt is based on a lot of google help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Zoom START");
  $('#zoom-in').click(function() {
    updateZoom(0.1);
    console.log("Zoomed in");
  });

  $('#zoom-out').click(function() {
    updateZoom(-0.1);
    console.log("Zoomed out");
  });


  zoomLevel = 1;

  var updateZoom = function(zoom) {
    zoomLevel += zoom;
    $('#imageblock').css({
      zoom: zoomLevel,
      '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')',
      /* Firefox */
      'transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')',
      //'-ms-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')', /* IE 9 */
      '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')',
      /* Safari and Chrome */
      //'-o-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')', /* Opera */

    });
    console.log("updated imageblock css");
  }
});
```

```css
#imageblock {
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 800px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#imageblock img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Image:</label>
<div class="readonly">
  <div>
    <b>Click to tag people, Ctrl-click to tag animals</b>
    <button type="button" id="zoom-in">zoom in</button> <button type="button" id="zoom-out">zoom out</button>
  </div>
  <div id="imageblock">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/v38pV.jpg" id="img1" doc_id="394" style="height:600px" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <a id="rotate" href="#">Rotate 90 degrees</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image zooms, but also grows to fill the page without any scrollbars, and does not stay within a viewport (image block). Thanks for any assistance/direction you can give me!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use an approach like this with a couple bounding elements to control the clipping and scrolling. See below:

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  $('img').css('transform', `scale(${$(this).val()})`);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: block;
}

img {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" step="0.1" value="1" min="0" />

<div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/250/250" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to give the parent div overflow: hidden

```
readonly{
overflow: hidden
}
```